# Combinatorially generating subgraphs between a given upper and lower bound (Sage)

Tags: python, combinatorics, sage

I am new to sage and I have been reading the documentation but this is very new territory for me and it is a bit tough to get a good grasp on everything.

What I want to do is, given an adjacency matrix, an upper bounds, and a lower bounds - generate all pathways through that matrix, where a "pathway" is comprised of one entry from each row, such that the weight of the pathway is equal to or between the bounds.

Even better would be if I could organize the given pathways by 1.)  The amount amount of edges with a lower weight in each row than the entry in the pathway, and/or 2.) Minimum overlap with other pathways in regards to #1.

For clarity, a quick example.
Given the 4x4 matrix:

```
[[1,2,3,4],
 [5,6,7,8],
 [10,11,12,13],
 [20,21,22,23]]
```

And an upper bound 38, and a lower bound 37, possible pathways could be:

2,5,10,20
3,5,10,20
2,6,10,20
2,5,11,20
2,5,10,21
etc etc.  I don't want to write out all the pathways, so hopefully you get the idea.

Even better would be if I could quickly filter out redundancy, by not including pathways that are subsets of other pathways (for example, 2,5,10,20 is encompassed by 3,5,10,20 - since for each pathway I plan on including all lower-weight edges of the each respective row).

Comment: I feel like I'm confused; how is this matrix an adjacency matrix?

Comment: The values in the matrix are edge weights.  Row position and col position are the nodes of the given edge.  So, say, weight 6 in this matrix is edge (1,1).  Now of course we shouldn't have an edge going from a node to itself, and that's a bit sloppy by me, but I was trying to convey the concept quickly.  It should have had 0s going down the diagonal.

Comment: I see, a weighted adjacency matrix.  Shouldn't it be symmetric, then?  Anyway, I'm still not 100% sure how this is related, but I'll at least put some links out that may help you.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a symmetric matrix (with or without diagonal entries nonzero) you can [do this](http://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJwlzbEKgzAUheFd8B2yGeEgqQp1cXZy6xZCSPU2KlYlpti-fWO7fcO5_21ZzZ7Gu_HNpRTIUaBUkDkErqgUmCwCBC7F6RJVEIRSaRxtblw8a-OoCY3GmW3gLR6rC7k6OWi0g6dem34yHS3dR__fJOGyyew53-bVc-ot6dncad7rm3sR9rNrf06zfVgPnn4BGtQzJQ==&lang=sage).

```
M = matrix([[0,2,3,4],[2,0,7,8], [3,7,0,13], [4,8,13,0]])
G = Graph(M,format='weighted_adjacency_matrix')
G.graphplot(edge_labels=True,spring=True).show()
```

And hopefully from `G` itself you could do what you want. (Unless it has nothing to do with graphs and only the matrix, in which case you may want a different thing entirely.)

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do (how do the "pathways" correspond to subgraphs?), and probably describing that would be beyond the scope of this site (as opposed to math.SX.com), but the [generic graph documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/generic_graph.html) has some path methods and the [undirected documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/graphs/sage/graphs/graph.html) may also prove helpful.